# Boosting multiple class classification trees in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, gbm

I'm trying to use gbm in R to create a boosting classification tree model for my data. 
 The problem is that I'm trying to classify my data into multiple labels and the only classification distribution I can find for gbm ("bernoulli") only works for binary classification. 
   Is there some change that I could make to my code to create a model which classifies the data into more than just two classes?

```
boost=gbm(label~., data=training, distribution="bernoulli", 
n.trees=5000, 
interaction.depth=4)
```

Comment: bernoulli means coin flip essentially. There's a bunch of distributions in [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
distribution = "multinomial"
```

Notice that, despite the fact that the option does not seem to be available in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gbm/versions/2.1.4/topics/gbm) of `gbm`, it **is** available indeed - check the example on top of page 30 of the [pdf manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf), where `gbm` with `distribution = "multinomial"` is used with the 3-class iris dataset.

Comment: @desertnaut `distribution = "multinomial"` seems to be an option of `gbm`; please, read page 8 (when describing `class.stratify.cv`)  and consider the example at the top of page 30 of the gbm manual: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf

Comment: @MarcoSandri You are right - my bad. Would be a good idea to pinpoint the fact (I edited the answer to reflect this)...